# Is it possible to identify the format of a string?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, bson

Is it possible to recognize if a string is formatted as a [BSON ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)?

For strings we could do:

```
"hello".is_a?(String) # => true
```

That would not work since the ObjectID is a String anyway. But is it possible to analyze the string to determine if it's formatted as a BSON ObjectID?

Usually, ObjectIDs have this format.

```
  52f4e2274d6f6865080c0000
```

The formatting criteria is [stated in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
> a 2-byte process id, and
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Comment: Are there any 12-byte hexadecimal strings which would *not* be valid BSON object IDs?

Comment: Are you using mongoid?

Comment: @ram yes, I am using Mongoid.

Comment: @Gareth not sure. But it's either that, or a parameterized name: `hello-there` or `whatever-blah-blah`.

Comment: You can never determine (for sure) if a certain text is written in a certain format. If a text fits a certain format, it does not mean that it does not fit another format. If a text fits a certain format and the content makes sense under human inspection, you can only probablistically estimate that that is the format it is written in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any 24 chararcters long hexadecimal string is a valid BSON object id, so you can check it using this regular expression:

```
'52f4e2274d6f6865080c0000' =~ /\A\h{24}\z/
# => 0
```

Both the [moped](http://rubydoc.info/gems/moped/1.5.2/Moped/BSON/ObjectId#legal?-class_method) (used by mongoid) and the [bson](http://rubydoc.info/gems/bson/2.2.0/BSON/ObjectId#legal?-class_method) (used by mongo_mapper) gems encapsulates this check in a `legal?` method:

```
require 'moped'
Moped::BSON::ObjectId.legal?('00' * 12)
# => true
```

```
require 'bson'
BSON::ObjectId.legal?('00' * 12)
# => true
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Mongoid` use: `.is_a?(Moped::BSON::ObjectId)` sytanx.

Example:

```
some_id = YourModel.first.id
some_id.is_a?(Moped::BSON::ObjectId)
```

**Note:**

"52d7874679478f45e8000001".is_a?(String)  # Prints true

Comment: if I try this in my model I get a `uninitialized constant Moped::BSON` Error.

Comment: Mongoid version? Check as gem list | grep 'mongoid'.

Comment: I got it to work. But I think this method will not work for me. The reason is I want to override the `find()` method in the model. So `find("52f4e21e4d6f686786000000")` will always evaluate to false since the finder is passing in a string.

Comment: Or you can convert your string into BSON Object as BSON::ObjectId('52f4e2274d6f6865080c0000')

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I can do `BSON::ObjectId.from_string("52f4e21e4d6f686786000000")` but then, if it's not, I would have to rescue `invalid id error`, which is ugly. Thanks for the help